# Differential equation : $(1+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}+2xy=(1-x^2)^k $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation:

$(1+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}+2xy=(1-x^2)^k \tag{$*$}$

,where $k\neq 0$ is a real number.

a) Find the general solution of this equation in the case that $k = \frac{1}{2}$.

b) Let $k\neq 0$ be arbitrary. Assume that $y(x)$ is a particular solution to (*) such that $y'(\frac{1}{2}) = 0$. What is $y(\frac{1}{2})$?

Determine whether $x = \frac{1}{2}$ is a local minima for $y(x)$, local maxima or neither.

I have solved the last part of b) by solving (*) for $\frac{dy}{dx}$, differentiating both sides of the equality with respect to $x$ and then substituting $x = \frac{1}{2}$ and $y = (\frac{3}{4})^k$ at the end. I was wondering whether there is an easier way to solve this.

Comment: It is a linear first order DE, so the general solution is obtainable through an integrating factor method.

Comment: Instead of solving for $dy/dx$ first and then differentiating, I suggest differentiating (*) first. Have in mind that if you want the value of $(fg)'$ at $x=a$ the knowledge that $g'(a)=0$, then $(fg)'(a)=f'(a)g(a)$, which make life very easy.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That did make the calculations a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

This is an exact differential equation

$$ \left(2xy-(1-x^2)^k\right)\,dx+(1+x^2)\,dy=0$$

since $\dfrac{\partial M}{dy}=2x$ and $\dfrac{\partial N}{dx}=2x$. So we get

$$f(x,y)=x^2y-\int(1-x^2)^kdx+C_1(y)$$
and
$$ f(x,y)=x^2y+y+C_2(x) $$

Therefore

$$ x^2y+y-\int(1-x^2)^kdx=c $$

$$y=\frac{\int(1-x^2)^kdx}{1+x^2}$$

In the case of $k=\frac{1}{2}$ there is a straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have the equation 
$$(1+x^2)y' + 2xy=(1-x^2)^k$$
and the $y$ described in $b$ satisfies $y'(1/2)=0$.

By the equation above, if $x=1/2$ then
$$(1+(1/2)^2)y'(1/2) + 2(1/2)y(1/2)=(1-(1/2)^2)^k,$$
$$y(1/2)=(1-(1/2)^2)^k,$$
$$y(1/2)=(3/4)^k.$$

Comment: He has already figured this part out, he knows $y=(3/4)^k$.

Comment: Yes. But he asked if there were a simple way of calculating it.

Comment: I think he is asking if there was a simpler way of finding out whether $x=1/2$ is a minimum, maximum or neither.